# Installing clip on bars, limited space available. Will an adhesive be neccesary?

Tags: motorcycle, steering, parts, installation

I'm planning to install clip on bars on my bike, however I have encountered a problem. If I install them in the traditional under the triple clamps position, they may lack clearance from the tank and headlight bracket. Another option would be to install them above the triple clamp as there is part of the fork sticking out

My Questions are:

- Would this be viable? (the protrusion is approximately 1cm high)
- If so would and adhesive (i.e Loctite) be necessary?

Bike in question: MV Agusta Brutale 675, MY 2014. Forks diameter: 50mm. Clip ons: Tomaselli, 50mm (subject to change)

Comment: Nice question +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's possibly viable**

- The 1cm of fork that is available to mount a clip-on to is a concern
- Locktite will not make it any safer

**Options**

Depending on how invested you are in clip-on's you could use standard cafe bike handlebars and mount them to your risers just like current handlebars are mounted.  Back in the 80's we used to just flip handlebars over in many cases to turn our bikes into cafe style rides.  This would obviously not work on your motorcycle because of the shape of your handlebars but you could procure some cafe style handlebars and attempt to use those.

Another possibility is to get clip-on handlebars and modify the mount that attaches to the fork in order to get the clearance required between the headlight mount and the fork.  You could have the bracket machined to slip in there.

Some clip on manufacturers use double sided pinch components that do not require you to slide the fork out of the top triple clamp.  Basically they are NOT clam-shell style and have the pinch bolts on either side of the bracket rather than on one side.  Woodcraft comes to mind as a manufacturer that accommodates this configuration.  Most racing clip-on's conform to this style as it is much quicker to replace broken clip-on's if you don't have to slide the fork down in the triple tree to mount them onto the bike.

**Image of Woodcraft clip-on's**

[image]

Notice how you can split the mount in two.  As well, the Woodcraft have a very thin gap and may just slide between the headlight mount and the fork on your bike.

**Opinion**

IMO you will want to find a way to mount clip-on's below the top triple clamp.  This will be a much safer configuration.  The last thing you need under heavy braking is the mount spinning on the fork creating a potentially unsafe situation for yourself.  You will want the entire clip-on mount grabbing the fork to prevent slippage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After remeasuring and consulting with my mechanic I think there may be space under the tripple clamp after all,  i am also considering mounting my Rizoma fatbars upside down, they may work.

Comment: I have the same set on my Aprilia.  I rode a season with those flipped over a couple of years ago.  Turned out to be a good feel and nice for counter steering.  Best of luck with that, would like to know how the project turns out.

Comment: If you want to know how the build is going check out my instagram: glenrules7. Im still planning it out, only got a refrence picture of how I hope the build will turn out.

Comment: Nice!  I'll check it out.